# ¿Como puedo construir un arreglo con los contenidos de multiples etiquetas HTML con la misma clase?

Tags: javascript, html, array, filtro

La cuestion es la siguiente: en mi documento HTML tengo multiples etiquetas `P`  con la clase precio, ejemplo `<p class="precio">` 400 `</p>`. Y quiero construir un arreglo que contenga los valores de todos esos parrafos.

la intención de crear este arreglo es para poder filtrarlos con javascript mediante filter() y hacer que los parrafos desaparezcan o aparezcan si cumplen con x condición

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero sería utilizar el `document.querySelectorAll` el cual puedes seleccionar una clase y te devolverá un array.
A continuación recorres ese array y guardas en otro array el contenido de cada uno de los elementos

```
var contenidos=new Array();
//Aquí ya te devuelve un array
var seleccion=document.querySelectorAll(".precio");
//Aquí recorres el array
for(item of seleccion){
    //Aquí guardas el contenido del elemento en un array
    contenidos.push(item.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: al final me di cuenta que no necesitaba hacer un arreglo para filtrar mis elementos html, lo que hice fue complicarme demas, pero solucionaste mi pregunta principal asi que ya esta hecho!, ademas eso del for (item of selecion) { } me sirvio para recorrer el contenido de todos los parrafos para luego filtrarlos con un if